# IBM Cloud - Nodemailer works on CloudFunctions, but gives an error on Watson Conversation

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm trying to integrate nodemailer and IBM Watson together. The issue is that the function works on the cloud functions, but when I integrate it with IBM Conversation, it gives me this error:

**Error Code:**

```
{"code":500,"msg":"Error","reason":{"code":"EENVELOPE","command":"API"}}
```

**This is the config:**

```
let smtpConfig = {
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: '587',
    auth: {
        user: '****', 
        pass: '****'
    },
    secureConnection: 'false',
    tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3',
        rejectUnauthorized: false

    }
};
```

- I have turned off 'Less secure app access', which still doesn't work.

Any idea what the error code means?

Comment: How have you integrated it with Watson Assistant / Conversation? What is your dialog node that includes the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You have to put `\\` before the `'@'` in the parameters for Watson.

**Wrong**: `"email": "email@gmail.com"`

**Correct**: `"email": "email\\@gmail.com"`